# Duvida Iniciante SQL

Tags: sql, query, jpa

Preciso saber o que as seguintes queries realizam, porém estou com dúvida, pois estou começando estudar agora SQL. Vocês podem me auxiliar?

```
"SELECT user_id, CAST(SUM(points_per_badge) AS INT) "
        + "FROM (SELECT p.user_id AS user_id, (COUNT(1) * b.quantity) AS points_per_badge "
        + "FROM CX_PUNCTUATION p JOIN CX_BADGE b ON b.id = p.badge_id WHERE p.user_id NOT IN :ignoredUsers "
        + "GROUP BY user_id, b.quantity) AS points_per_user GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1"
```

e

```
"SELECT p.badge_id, CAST((COUNT(1) * b.quantity) AS INT) "
            + "FROM CX_PUNCTUATION p JOIN CX_BADGE b ON b.id = p.badge_id WHERE p.user_id = :userId "
            + "GROUP BY p.badge_id, b.quantity"
```

Comment: Explique melhor o que você quer dizer com `traduzir`. Quer saber o que elas fazem?

Comment: Se está começando agora, fica a sugestão de esquecer essas queries e aprender o básico primeiro. Vai ser muito mais fácil.

Answer (score 0):

A primeira query está retornando o ID, está realizando uma soma e colocando o resultado dessa soma com inteiro, depois essas aspas e o sinal de + está concatenando(juntando) juntando o resultado com o resultado de outros SELECT's que está sendo realizado abaixo para trazer tudo numa mesma linha, depois está agrupando(Group By) e ordenando(Order By). O segundo SELECT está  retornando o ID e o resultado de uma multiplicação da contagem com a quantidade e novamente colocando esse valor como inteiro, no final está agrupando esse resultado pelo ID e quantidade. É relativamente simples essa query, mas acho que devia começar por coisas mais básicas para entender melhor e ir progredindo em linguagem SQL.